# Rest/Graphql apis and event driven architecture

Tags: apache-kafka, graphql, apache-pulsar, event-driven-design

I've been looking at the event driven architecture and it's seems it might be the right architecture for a project I'm working on.

But there is one thing I don't really get yet, what is the best practice/common pattern when your micro services are being consumed by front-end applications?

For my project, I have a web app and an iOS and Android app.

Let's take a simple case of a feature letting users create their profile.

Let's say I send the profile data via REST/GraphQL to the api endpoint which triggers microservices (running behind Kafka or Pulsar).

How can I get the result of the profile creation and then maybe use it on the next screen?

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

websocket calls to Pulsar will do most of what you want https://pulsar.apache.org/docs/en/client-libraries-websocket/

You could also call Apache Pulsar via MQTT which is not too uncommon from cell phones.

Or use a REST gateway or microservice between the app and Pulsar services.   I use Apache NiFi for that.